# Scaling won't work on some pages (Bootstrap 3 via SharePoint 2013)

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

I'm using Bootstrap 3 on a site I built with SharePoint 2013. I added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />` in my header but when I open my site via Mobile, the scaling doesn't seem to work on all pages (could be just content based ones but I'm not sure). Any ideas????

Comment: Which mobile browser are you using?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site for this question.